# Get last day where user was active in pd DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a df with just days of activity I can add a column `pev_day` by

```
# make sure vals are sorted
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'date'])
# add col with prev date
df['prev_date'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].shift()
```

Now I have a different dataset where I have not just the "active" days but some days of inactivity in between. How could I get around this issue to achieve this:

```
id date       active prev_date
A  01-01-2021 1      NaN
A  02-01-2021 1      01-01-2021
A  03-01-2021 0      02-01-2021
A  04-01-2021 0      02-01-2021
A  05-01-2021 1      02-01-2021
A  06-01-2021 1      05-01-2021
[..]
B  01-01-2021 1      NaN
B  02-01-2021 0      01-01-2021
[..]
```

Comment: Please provide an example input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, one way is to use `where` to mask the dates without activity and `ffill` to propagate the date with the last activity. Then like you did with `groupby.shift`.

```
# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':['A']*6 + ['B']*6,
    'date': pd.date_range('2021-07-01', freq='d', periods=12),
    'activity': [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1]
})

# create the prev_date column
df['prev_date'] = (
    df['date'].where(df['activity'].astype(bool)) #mask dates without activity
      .ffill() # propagate last date with activity
      .groupby(df['id']).shift() # shift the dates per group of id
)
print(df)
   id       date  activity  prev_date
0   A 2021-07-01         1        NaT
1   A 2021-07-02         1 2021-07-01
2   A 2021-07-03         0 2021-07-02
3   A 2021-07-04         0 2021-07-02
4   A 2021-07-05         0 2021-07-02
5   A 2021-07-06         1 2021-07-02
6   B 2021-07-07         1        NaT
7   B 2021-07-08         0 2021-07-07
8   B 2021-07-09         0 2021-07-07
9   B 2021-07-10         1 2021-07-07
10  B 2021-07-11         0 2021-07-10
11  B 2021-07-12         1 2021-07-10
```

Comment: thanks for the idea! unfortunately, this solution only works if there was activity on the first entry per user! try this data to reproduce: `'activity': [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1]` 

Would love to figure out a solution - this is exactly what I needed but this error makes it unusable. 

In other words: currently the last date of any activity is propagated. I want to propagate the last date of activity ONLY if it is from the same user-id

Comment: @ksbawpn right, remove the `ffill` and put it in the groupby like `.groupby(df['id']).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().shift())`, should work